# R: creating a variable on the fly

Tags: r

I would like to ask for some help in creating a sequence of variables v1,v2,... **while** running a program.
I run the following code for one such variable:

```
FinishAt <- 1
Sequence <- 1:FinishAt
AsCharacterSequence <- as.character(Sequence)

aa <- paste("v", AsCharacterSequence[1], sep="", collapse="") # [1] "v1"
bb <- eval(substitute(variable), list(variable=as.name(a))) # v1
```

The problem I face is how we shall make v1 a variable with a value (let's say 5).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why would you want to do that rather than using an array?

Comment: @nico: Because I want to control the names of the variables.@Karsten W: v1 is not a variable yet in order to use assign. The only variables that exist are aa and bb.

Comment: Your code seems incomplete. What is `AsCharacterSequence`, and what is `a`? Maybe you should look at `?assign`

Comment: You will be better off using a list and indexing the name. See FAQ: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f

Comment: @Apostolos: doesn't matter if v1 is not a variable yet, `assign` creates the variable, so Karsten code works. Still, I do not understand the point in this. What do you mean that you want to "control the names of the variables"?

Comment: It is resolved: assign(aa, 5). Then > v1 and we get [1] 5. Thank you all.@nico: You are right.It is better using an array/list. Otherwise karsten's thought is fine.

Comment: What values do these on the fly variables take? integers, data frames?

Comment: Maybe @KarstenW. can repost his comment as an answer?

Comment: @Maiasaura: I use `assign` when I don't know ahead of time what the object's name will be (such as when it is stored as a character string in another object). e.g. `foo <- paste(sample(LETTERS, 5), collapse=''); assign(foo, 'baz')` will assign baz to the object with this random string of letters as its name. The list idea is clever, but is something similar possible with that approach?

Comment: @jbaums: The FAQ to which @Maiasaura refers states that it is more R-idiomatic to deal with sequences of variables as lists rather than using a macro-style approach that works by processing variable names. The answer to "how do I handle an arbitrary variable name that is stored as a character string" is certainly `assign`/`get`, but the appropriate question as always is "what problem are you trying to solve?" -- in other words, I wonder how you got into the situation where you had a variable name stored in this way in the first place, and whether there isn't a better approach ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define variables on the fly with `assign`. For example, the following generates three variables v1 ... v3:

```
var_names <- paste("v", 1:3, sep="")
for (v in var_names) assign(v, runif(1))
```

The counterpart to `assign` is `get`, that is, if you want the values of the variables, use something like:

```
bb <- sapply(var_names, get)
```

Also note that both `assign` and `get` have an optional `envir` parameter, which enables you to keep those variables away from the rest of your code.

I am not sure, but I think it is possible that if there are many variables, assign/get is faster than a list, at least if you want to look up some values.